# How can I prevent Task Scheduler from running a script its set to at logoff when I'm disconnecting from rdp

Tags: windows-7

I have scripts connect & delete NFS shares at logon/logoff. Whenever I d/c from my rdp session it runs the 'at logoff' one & I need it not to.

Comment: Out of interest: What is the trigger you are using on the scheduled task? "When a specific Event is logged?  Also, what is the script written in? A batch file, VBS, etc?  Are you able to put a condition in the script based on the logged on session logontype?  E.g. See: Win32_LogonSession - LogonType could be used in the script, maybe session.exe in a batch file, etc...

Comment: Screenshots of pertinent settings: https://imgur.com/a/OCJV2